# static js doesn't load -- Django

Tags: django, django-templates

As far as I know I've followed all the steps to properly load my static files.  I was able to load a jpg in my template following [the instructions here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/):

However, my Javascript files from my static folder are not loading.

Here is my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %} 
<html>
  <head>
    {% block js %}
    <script src="{% static "js/p5" %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <title>Rango</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

in settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
```

I definitely have `p5.js` located in `/static/js/p5.js`, and django.contrib.staticfiles is in my installed apps.  When I go to any sites inheriting from base.html, firebug shows that no JS files are being loaded.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<script src="{% static "js/p5" %}"></script>` to `<script src="{% static "js/p5.js" %}"></script>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37546991/1324033)

That javascript file is only included in the *default* block. since you're overriding it, it is not included. So move the block scope below the javascripts to include extra js

```
{% block js %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/p5.js"
{% endblock %}
```

should be

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/p5.js' %}"></script>
{% block js %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks again, I see my problem.  When I try to inherit from base.html and extend the js, I get "
TemplateSyntaxError at /grow/

Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'"

Am I not supposed to put my <script>'s between {% block js%}{% endblock %} in templates inheriting from base?

Comment: @DavidJ. - You need to `load staticfiles` in your inherited template. Although that is a separate issue.